# Image analysis software

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I plan to install Ubuntu on a [pandaboard](http://www.pandaboard.org/)/[beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org/bone) in an industrial machine to assure the quality control of the products before they are processed by the machine.

So the idea is to connect a screen to the board, and an usb camera. Take a picture, compare the picture of the current product with the "reference" picture and if it's not the same, display a alert on the screen to inform the operator of the non-conformity of the products.

My question is : Which open source software/library could assist me in the analysis of the taken picture with fine-grain control of different parameters (color, gray level, brightness...etc) ?

Thank you.

Ps : It will be a desktop edition of Ubuntu in order to display the message on the screen, and let the operator interact with the automate (touch-screen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision), which is a library of programming functions for real time computer vision.

Comment: I was currently reading the wikipedia page of the OpenCV project, and was going to answer my own question. You were faster :o) Thank you anyway !